# When using a database that is supposedly thread-safe, do I need to synchronize my own threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, rethinkdb, nosql

I'm writing a Python application that uses a Rethink database. I have three worker threads that need to run and possibly access the database at the same time. I know how to synchronize threads in Python, but my question is: do I need to? If Rethink claims to be thread-safe, which is implied [on this page](http://rethinkdb.com/docs/troubleshooting/#my-insert-queries-are-slow-how-can-i-speed-them-up) giving advice on how to speed things up, can I leave pass the concurrency issues off to the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RethinkDB definitely works when accessed concurrently from multiple threads or clients.  The Python driver should work fine on multiple threads as long as you open a separate connection for each thread.

Answer (score 0):

You still need logic to handle concurrent writes to the same key.